# How do I format my data in R for it to show a new column with values as a percentage of the column total for each relevant period?

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I am new to R and I have the following data frame (called mydata1) in csv format:

```
Period     Market     Amount
FY 15-16    UK        500
FY 15-16    France    200
FY 15-16    Germany   300
FY 15-16    Poland    100
FY 16-17    UK        700
FY 16-17    France    500
FY 16-17    Germany   200
FY 16-17    Poland    100
```

I need that data frame to show me a new column with the weight of each Market (in terms of percentage) over the Total Amount of its relevant period.

I am showing below an Excel pivot table made using that same data (to better help in understanding what I am looking for):

[image: Screenshot 1]

I want my new data frame (let's call it mydata2) in R to look like the following:

[image: Screenshot 2]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error message when I run it:
mydata2 <- ave(df$Amount, df$Period, FUN = function(x) 100*x/sum(x))

Error in df$Period : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: I tried finding out how to use dput here: https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3688652

However, I am afraid I'm still stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Period) %>%
  mutate(pct_year = Amount/sum(Amount)*100) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed. That was really helpful!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!